# Название должности: заглавная или строчная?

Tags: строчная

Правительство в течение долгого времени требовало принятия этой меры, и потому она естественным путем вошла в программу реформ, утвержденную Первым Консулом.

Как следует писать словосочетание "Первый консул"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В большинстве случаев используется  строчная буква** (это не высшая должность в официальных документах).

Из Википедии: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Французский_консулат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82)

Конституция, вручая верховную исполнительную власть трем консулам, назначала на 10-летний срок **первым консулом** — Бонапарта, **вторым** — Камбасереса и **третьим** (на 5-летний срок) — Лебрена.

В Нацкорпусе также все используют **строчную букву (21 пример), за исключением Карамзина**.

1) Наполеон в ноябре 1799 года совершил переворот, стал **первым консулом,** а в 1804 году ― императором, расправил крылья, обрел мощь и затем, уже после смерти Суворова, завоевал всю Европу и занял Москву. [Сергей Баймухаметов. Триумфальная арка (2003) // «Вестник США», 2003.10.15]

Наполеон был избран **первым консулом** и семья его перебралась в Люксембургский дворец. [П. И. Ковалевский. Наполеон I и его гений (1900-1910)]

2) Сия минута без сомнения может назваться приятнейшею минутою Фоксовой жизни, и отличная благосклонность, изъявленная ему **Первым Консулом**, наградила его самым лестным образом  [Н. М. Карамзин].

Answer (score 1):

Названия должностей пишутся со строчной буквы. С прописной буквы пишутся названия высших государственных должностей в официальных текстах,напр.: **Президент Российской Федерации, Председатель Правительства РФ, Председатель Государственной думы, Премьер-министр Индии, Её Величество Королева Англии.**

> Однако в неофициальных текстах эти названия пишутся со строчной буквы, напр.: выборы президента, выступление председателя Госдумы, распоряжение премьер-министра, приём у королевы.

См.: [Академический справочник](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=90#pp90)

Answer (score -1):

Здесь контекст важен. Если используется как условное имя собственное первого лица государства (ну типа прозвища Наполеона I), то возможна прописная в первом слове. Иначе - обе строчные. Здесь скорее всего именно первый случай случай, то есть имеется в виду не должность, а именно лицо, за ней стоящее. Поэтому, как вариант, заглавная возможна.

Comment: А при чём тут прозвище Наполеона? Должность первого консула Франции он действительно занимал в 1799-1804 гг., а "маленький капрал" (le petit caporal), тут вроде как не к месту.

Comment: @МаркИз я не про маленького капрала, а именно про условное наименование личности через должность, "Первый консул". Это особый вид имен собственных. Что до Наполеона, то речь, не сомневаюсь, именно о нем.

Comment: @МаркИз Вот близкий пример. "Седьмой, Седьмой, я - Первый!". Здесь за номерами стоят должности, а за ними - физические лица. Пишется с заглавной. Если за "Первым консулом" стоит именно Наполеон, а не его должность, то заглавная возможна.

Comment: "Седьмой, Седьмой, я - Первый!" - это не должности, а позывные. Должности же везде кроме официальных текстов (по Лопатину) или некоторых исключений (по Розенталю) пишутся со строчной.

Comment: @МаркИз  *это не должности, а позывные* - вот и я о том, что "Первый консул" здесь **не должность**, а лицо за ним стоящее. Позывной - частный случай имени собственного. Розенталю я здесь не возражаю, Вы просто не потрудились понять написанное.