# Титулы и достижения: с заглавной или строчной?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Похожий вопрос уже задавался относительно [государственных должностей](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/38015/186102) ([и не раз](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/432078/186102)) и [государственных же титулов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/6780/186102).

А что насчёт спортивных и выставочных достижений? Возьмём, к примеру, кинологию. С какой буквы их надо начинать? Примеры (буквы, о которых идёт речь, выделены жирным):

1. **П**обедитель класса.
2. **Л**учший **в**етеран.
3. **Ч**емпион ОАНКОО.
4. **К**андидат в **Ч**емпионы **Ф**едерации ОАНКОО.
5. **Л**учший **п**редставитель породы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбор буквы зависит от того, **нарицательным или собственным** является сочетание в данном тексте.

**Именем собственным** (с прописной буквы пишется первое слово и входящие имена собственные) являются **названия титулов и сертификатов**, например: Собака получила титул "Победитель класса юниоров".

**Титулы и сертификаты:** Победитель класса, Лучший ветеран, Чемпион ОАНКОО, 
Кандидат в Чемпионы Федерации ОАНКОО, Лучший представитель породы.

В других случаях (строчная буква) это **нарицательное сочетание,** например:

Для записи собак в **класс победителей** необходимо предоставить сертификат.  При расшифровке титулов: CW – **победитель класса**, присваивается первой собаке в классе, получившей высшую оценку.

https://vk.com/topic-49098181_27676600

http://rkf.org.ru/documents/regulations/page428

Comment: То есть, если мы *перечисляем* титулы конкретной собаки, то каждый из них пишется с заглавной?

Comment: Да, потому что титул - это имя собственное.

Comment: @ Sibylla, если считать название титула именем собственным, чем тогда можно объяснить строчную в других титулов?

Comment: Рассмотрим любую тему, например шахматы, там такая же ситуация:  (1) Первым официальным чемпионом мира по шахматам стал Вильгельм Стейниц в 1886 году. (2) Звание «Чемпион мира по шахматам» индус получает в 2007 году, обойдя Владимира Крамника.

Answer (score 2):

Я обратился на Грамму.ру, пришел ответ. Вот что они ответили.

Нужно признать, что правила употребления строчных и прописных букв относятся к той области орфографии, которую весьма трудно урегулировать навсегда и окончательно. Дело в том, что у прописной буквы имеется несколько основных функций: в том числе морфологическая (выделение имен собственных) и так называемая ранговая (выделением какой-либо номинации при помощи прописной буквы пишущий стремится подчеркнуть высокий статус называемого им объекта). Описать все возможные случаи употребления прописной в ранговой функции невозможно, поэтому противоречия в рекомендациях различных словарей и справочников неизбежны. Однако в том, что касается титулования, лингвисты вполне солидарны: с прописной буквы пишутся только названия высших государственных должностей и титулов, а также высших церковных должностных лиц, причем только в официальных текстах (в к каковым относятся государственные документы).

> Поэтому корректно со строчной: **чемпион Олимпийских игр, чемпион ОАНКОО и т. п. 
>   Корректно также: Собака получила титул победителя класса юниоров; титул лучшего представителя породы и т. п.**